# What is wrong with this command line argument using $or operator in node.js application?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

```js
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
  assert = require('assert');

var allOptions = [{
  overview: "wiki",
}, {
  milestones: "CMO"
}];

var numQueriesFinished = 0;
var companiesSeen = {};

for (var i = 0; i < allOptions.length; i++) {
  var query = queryDocument(allOptions[i]);
  queryMongoDB(query, i);
}



function queryMongoDB(query, queryNum) {

  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/crunchbase', function(err, db) {

    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Successfully connected to MongoDB for query: " + queryNum);

    var cursor = db.collection('companies').find(query);

    var numMatches = 0;

    cursor.forEach(
      function(doc) {
        numMatches = numMatches + 1;
        if (doc.permalink in companiesSeen) return;
        companiesSeen[doc.permalink] = doc;
      },
      function(err) {
        assert.equal(err, null);
        console.log("Query " + queryNum + " was:" + JSON.stringify(query));
        console.log("Matching documents: " + numMatches);
        numQueriesFinished = numQueriesFinished + 1;
        if (numQueriesFinished == allOptions.length) {
          report();
        }
        return db.close();
      }
    );

  });

}


function queryDocument(options) {

  var query = {};

  if ("overview" in options) {

    query.overview = {
      $or: [overview: {
          "$regex": options.overview,
          "$options": "i"
        },
        tag_list: {
          "$regex": options.overview,
          "$options": "i"
        }
      ]
    };
  }

  if ("milestones" in options) {
    query["milestones.source_description"] = {
      "$regex": options.milestones,
      "$options": "i"
    };
  }

  return query;

}


function report(options) {
  var totalEmployees = 0;
  for (key in companiesSeen) {
    totalEmployees = totalEmployees + companiesSeen[key].number_of_employees;
  }

  var companiesList = Object.keys(companiesSeen).sort();
  console.log("Companies found: " + companiesList);
  console.log("Total employees in companies identified: " + totalEmployees);
  console.log("Total unique companies: " + companiesList.length);
  console.log("Average number of employees per company: " + Math.floor(totalEmployees / companiesList.length));
}
```

In the above code, I need to write an assignment statement to ensure that if "overview" appears in the `options` object, we will match documents that have the value of `options.overview` in either the "overview" field or "tag_list" field of companies documents.

I tried the `$or`:

`query.overview = {$or: [overview : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options": "i"}, tag_list : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options": "i"}]};`

I'm getting the below error:

[image]

And when I try [@MykolaBorysyuk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39105869/2404470): `query.overview = {$or: [{overview : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options":"i"}}, {tag_list : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options": "i"}} ]};`

I get

[image]

What is wrong with this command line argument using $or operator in node.js application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

$or operator in array should contain objects. So query should look like this.

```
query.overview = {$or: [{overview : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options":"i"}}, {tag_list : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options": "i"}} ]};
```

**Edit.**

Here is your problem. When you using $or operator you must pass it first always. 
So query can look like this `{$or: [...]}` but cant look like this `{somefield: {$or:[]}}` <- that will cause your error. https://gyazo.com/cb993ecdcbc8f37052878a34d9a27549

To fix your code do this

```
var cursor = db.collection('companies').find(query.overview);
```

To fix your query builder:

```
function queryDocument(options) {
  var query = {};
  var arrayOfParams = [];

 if ("overview" in options) {
    arrayOfParams.push({overview: {
      "$regex": options.overview,
      "$options": "i"
    }});

    arrayOfParams.push({tag_list: {
      "$regex": options.overview,
      "$options": "i"
    }});  
 }

 if ("milestones" in options) {
    arrayOfParams.push({milestones: {
      "$regex": options.milestones,
      "$options": "i"
    }});
 }
  query.overview = {$or: arrayOfParams};
  return query;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm getting another error. `$or` is not defined kind of.

Comment: Okay...Lets make it simple. Try like this -> collection.find({$or: [{overview : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options":"i"}}, {tag_list : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options": "i"}} ]})..will you have same error? Im thinking you have something like this coll.find({query.overview = {$or:...}) which can cause a lot of errors.

Comment: Silly question - is it kind of some indexing issue? The issue is still there

Comment: I don't think indexing is the issue here; it's the scope of the question which is not clear and how you are going about it to solve it. I've noticed a lot of mistakes in your code, for instance and for a start you are looping through the `allOptions` array and sending an asynchronous request to mongodb within the loop which is an anti-pattern. It's hard to follow what you are trying to achieve in your program, I believe it needs a simple approach.

Comment: @chridam I do agree with you. I've just started learning `node.js` on my own. I may need your help in my efforts :)

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk Okey, what if I also **have** to pass `query["milestones.source_description"]` as well in the same query?

Comment: You need to change you query builder to make somethig like this {$or: [{overview : {"$regex": options.overview, "$options":"i"}}, {"$regex": options.milestones,"$options": "i"}]}..So i would suggest for start build array and push all query parameters that you need and then add this into query.overview.$or key. I will try to fix it now.

Comment: @MykolaBorysyuk Thanks a ton! Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

first you should be sure that you understand the question and the tool you are going to use.

now please look at the query you were using. `query.overview = ...` in Node.JS is eq to `find({overveiw:...})` in mongodb shell. here you are checking the value of the `overview` field in database.

but you were asking to check either the `overview` field or the `tag_list` field are eq to the value of `options.overview`. in mongo shell given query will look like this:

```
find({$or:[{"overview":{$exists:true,$regex: options.overview, "$options":"i"}},{"tag_list":{$exists:true,$regex: options.overview, "$options":"i"}}]})
```

so you were very close to the right answer. your query could look like this:

```
query = {$or:[{"overview":{$exists:true,$regex: options.overview, "$options":"i"}},{"tag_list":{$exists:true,$regex: options.overview, "$options":"i"}}]};
```

i checked if fields exist, but this is optional.

good luck)